# How to change width of a barcode in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need to customize width of an barcode.
i have try it using this, i have using jquery-barcode.js plugin.(http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode.html)

```
$("#barcodeView").barcode(
"123456789023F", // Value barcode (dependent on the type of barcode)
"code128", // type (string)
{ barWidth: 1, barHeight: 50 }
);
```

but it was customizing the width and height of single bar. i need to adjust widt and height of a whole barcode. this is my html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" >
                <div id="barcodeView"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Which plugin is `barcode`? Link?

Comment: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just going through the [demo page](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Based-Barcode-Generator-Barcode/) for the Plugin you are using. The bar code is made of several `divs` representing individual bars and therefore the whole container i.e the `div` with id "barcodeTarget" just can't be resized to fit your needs. You can explicitly set it's `width` but it won't 'resize' the entire barcode like you want.

However the `barWidth` and `barHeight` attributes are simply the width and height of all the `divs` representing the individual bars (in pixels). So you can set those attributes to anything and correspondingly resize the entire barcode. You can obviously limit the width of the container like I mentioned but it wouldn't affect the width of the bars in the bar code. I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" >
            <div id="barcodeView" style="width:200px;"></div>
        </div>
```

**OR**

```
  <style>
     #barcodeView{
         width:12.5em;

      }

  </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to specify the width of the object *#Barcode*, you can add some css :

```
<style>
#Barconde {
     width:200px;
}
</style>
```

I think it should work, but I do not know the Barcode API.

Comment: what id i need to use this is my html<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" >
                    <div id="barcodeView"></div>
                </div>

Comment: You just have to use my code, with the ID of your Barecode : **barcodeView**

Answer (score 0):

This would work anyways

```
<style>
    #barcodeView{
        width:200px !important;
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Also have a look at this link https://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcode/source/browse/trunk/jquery-barcode/demo/demo.html?r=11

Answer (score 0):

Here goes my workaround:

```
barcodediv.barcode(txtBarcode, "code128", { barWidth: 2, barHeight: 70, moduleSize: 5, showHRI: false, addQuietZone: true, marginHRI: 5, bgColor: "#FFFFFF", color: "#000000", fontSize: 10, output: "css", posX: 0, posY: 0 });
barcodediv.css({ transform: 'scale(.75)'});
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to increase the width of whole barcode, you'll need to increase the width of each bar (barWidth in settings).

You can find that customization in settings below:

```
    var settings = {
      output:renderer,
      bgColor: $("#bgColor").val(),
      color: $("#color").val(),
      barWidth: $("#barWidth").val(),
      barHeight: $("#barHeight").val(),
      moduleSize: $("#moduleSize").val(),
      posX: $("#posX").val(),
      posY: $("#posY").val(),
      addQuietZone: $("#quietZoneSize").val()
    };
```

Comment: but i have using 1 as width.

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana in this case could please create a fiddle? and share it!